# PHPunit throws an error error thrown if i use multiple arguments in my Dataprovider

Tags: php, phpunit

I i use as a dataprovider:

```
/**
  * @return array[]
  */
 function BackStagePassData(): array
 {
    return [
        'normal increase' => [[15,20],[14,21]],
    ];
 }
```

for:

```
function testBackStagePasses($start,$end)
{
    $app = new GildedRose([new BackStagePass($start[0],$start[1])]);
    $app->updateQuality();

    $this->assertEquals($app->items[0]->sellIn,$end[0]);
    $this->assertEquals($app->items[0]->quality,$end[1]);
}
```

everything works fine but if i expand to:

```
 function BackStagePassData(): array
    {
        return [
            'normal increase' => [[15,20],[14,21]],
            'higher incresae' => [[10,20],[9,22]]
        ];
    }
```

it throws an error:

```
TypeError : Cannot assign null to property GildedRose\Items\Item::$quality of type int
 /var/www/html/guilded_rose/php/src/GildedRose.php:32
 /var/www/html/guilded_rose/php/tests/ApprovalTest.php:94
```

i tries adding extra parentheses with no luck, what should i do?

Comment: That is because these are completely two different things. Use a Generator instead. https://3v4l.org/h9PIq PHPUnit makes a call for one array as dataset. With the Generator you can yield each dataset.

Comment: the data provider looks okay, except the typo in `higher incresae`. i guess it's a problem with generating the GuildedRoseItem, which we currently don't see. Try to generate the BackStagePass first, check, if this one works and after that, you can create the guildedRose object. My guess, the BackstagePass is null when you gave it the start and end values...

Comment: With some puzzeling i found out that problem whas with underlying code, this code works just fine, problem solved